# Remove random number from rewrite url

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url, url-rewrite

i am working on magento category. my requirement is if request path already exist than no need to add second time.

also if request path exist than no need to add that path second time in url rewrite and also should not generate url containing random number for category url.

i have found it in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url` but unable to find how to stop.